# Date minus 1 year?

Tags: php, date

I've got a date in this format:

```
2009-01-01
```

How do I return the same date but 1 year earlier?

Comment: Don't forget to tend to the semantic issue of what you mean by "one year" w.r.t. leap years.  Subtracting 365 days from 2008-02-28 will give you 2007-02-28, while subtracting 365 days from 2008-02-29 will give you 2007-03-31.

Comment: I guess that it very much depends on what "subtracting a year" means. You could mean the same month and day but one year earlier or the month and day after subtracting 365 days as Hostile points out.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$date = strtotime('2010-01-01 -1 year');
```

The `strtotime` function returns a unix timestamp, to get a formatted string you can use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', $date); // echoes '2009-01-01'
```

Answer (score 123):

Use `strtotime()` function:

```php
$time = strtotime("-1 year", time());
$date = date("Y-m-d", $time);
```

Comment: > `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year'));`

Answer (score 66):

Using the DateTime object...

```
$time = new DateTime('2099-01-01');
$newtime = $time->modify('-1 year')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Or using now for today

```
$time = new DateTime('now');
$newtime = $time->modify('-1 year')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Can just do `$time = new DateTime('now - 1 year'); echo $time->format('Y-m-d');`.

Answer (score 41):

an easiest way which i used and worked well

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year'));
```

this worked perfect.. hope this will help someone else too.. :)

Answer (score 11):

Although there are many acceptable answers in response to this question, I don't see any examples of the `sub` method using the `\Datetime` object: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

So, for reference, you can also use a `\DateInterval` to modify a `\Datetime` object:

```
$date = new \DateTime('2009-01-01');
$date->sub(new \DateInterval('P1Y'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Which returns:

```
2008-01-01
```

For more information about `\DateInterval`, refer to the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 10):

On my website, to check **if registering people is 18 years old**, I simply used the following :

```
$legalAge = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-18 year'));
```

After, only compare the the two dates.

Hope it could help someone.

Answer (score 9):

```
// set your date here
$mydate = "2009-01-01";

/* strtotime accepts two parameters.
The first parameter tells what it should compute.
The second parameter defines what source date it should use. */
$lastyear = strtotime("-1 year", strtotime($mydate));

// format and display the computed date
echo date("Y-m-d", $lastyear);
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use the following function to subtract 1 or any years from a date.

```
 function yearstodate($years) {

        $now = date("Y-m-d");
        $now = explode('-', $now);
        $year = $now[0];
        $month   = $now[1];
        $day  = $now[2];
        $converted_year = $year - $years;
        echo $now = $converted_year."-".$month."-".$day;

    }

$number_to_subtract = "1";
echo yearstodate($number_to_subtract);
```

And looking at above examples you can also use the following

```
$user_age_min = "-"."1";
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($user_age_min.'year'));
```