# Current date minus 4 month?

Tags: php, date

I have date in this format (YYYYMM):

```
201201  // Gen, 2012
201202  // Feb, 2012
201203  // ecc
```

Let's say from 201203 I want to subtract 4 months. I can't do `201203  - 4` because it's = `201199`

`201203 - 4` should output `201111` (Nov, 2011)

Maybe i should convert my string to a date and then pass it to strtotime with -4 month?

Any suggest ?

Comment: look at functions explode and mktime.

Comment: @OZ_, what help would explode be here?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php) in PHP:

```
$date = strtotime('2012-05-01 -4 months');
```

This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990321/date-minus-1-year) will help you.

Answer (score 9):

`strtotime()` can do it but you will need to add a day of the month for it to parse the date:

```
$input = '201203';

$input .= '01';

$date = strtotime($input .' -4 months');

echo date('Ym', $date);
```

Outputs Nov 2011:

```
201111
```

Answer (score 8):

Apart from the `strtotime` versions, since PHP 5.3 you can also use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Ym", "201201");
$interval = new DateInterval("P4M"); // 4 months
$fourMonthsEarlier = $date->sub($interval);
echo $fourMonthsEarlier->format("Ym");
```

Answer (score 2):

Final_date = Currentdate - 4 months

```
<?php
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");

$final_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($current_date." -4 months"));

echo $final_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

for EX $da=2014-04-01

if u want to minus 6 months use this..

```
$date = strtotime($da .' -4 months');
$final=date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

echo $final;

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert the string to a UNIX timestamp, which is in seconds. `time()` will give you the current UNIX timestamp. Subtract them to get how old the date is in seconds, and divide by `60*60*24` to get it in days

Answer (score 0):

Previous code not working:

```
$da='2014-08-29';
$date = strtotime($da .' -6 months');
$final=date('Y-m-d', $date);
echo $final;
$date = strtotime($da .' -7 months');
$final=date('Y-m-d', $date);
echo $final;
```

February is missing!

Comment: only 29th of February missing

Answer (score -1):

```
$date = '2016-09-01 00:00:00.000000';

$date2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s.u", strtotime($date." -4 months"));

echo $date2;
```

on run this code you will get   2016-05-01 00:00:00.000000