# PHP How to find the date and time one year and one day ago when it's a leap year

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to get php to calculate a date that was one year and one day ago. I have this:

```
$date = date(strtotime('-366 days'));
$oneyear_oneday = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date); 

$date = date(strtotime('-1 year'));
$oneyear = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
```

However, due to it being a leap year, both $oneyear and $oneyear_oneday provide the same output. Does anyone know how I can calculate this correctly?

ie if it's 3pm on 15th August 2012, I want the output to be 3pm on the 15th August 2011

Comment: What's wrong with `$oneyear`? Seems to give the correct output...?

Comment: Your date(strtotime()) calls are incorrect. 1st arg for date() is a format string, and you're passing in the raw time value. strtotime already returns a timestamp, so there's no need to "date-ify" it until you're ready to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, subtract one year. Then, subtract one day from the result:

```
$date = strtotime('-1 day', strtotime('-1 year'));
$oneyear_oneday = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
```

Comment: So simple! I knew there would be an answer, I just couldn't think outside the box!

Answer (score 3):

with PHP5.3,

```
   $date = new DateTime();
   $interval = new DateInterval("P1Y");
   $newdate = $date->sub($interval);
```

Comment: Everyone, please use the newer DateTime classes like this example and not the old non-OO date() functions.

Comment: While I agree to use the newer DateTime, I also think the old non-OO date() functions are fine for simple stuff.

Comment: @J.Bruni: I love the DateTime/Interval/Period/Zone classes because they take care of edge cases. I don't have to worry about leap years or daylight savings time or timezones goofing up my calculations. While the old functions still work, I tend not to use them even in *simple* cases, because who knows when an edge case will pop up and blindside you.

Comment: I think that maybe because of using PHP for so long, and having faced all these tricky edge cases (interval, leap, DST, zones, etc), I became experienced and comfortable with the old functions, while I don't have all this experience with the new ones.

Comment: @dnagirl: Thanks for that, but I'm currently on PHP Version 5.2.17 so I'm going to go with the answer from J. Bruni below.

Comment: @SamStones Ouch, you should consider upgrading

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)...

Comment: OK, why? Any example achieving what the OP tries to do?

Comment: ```date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(date('H'), date('i'), date('s'), date('n'), date('j'), date('Y')-1))``` gives the same.

Answer (score 0):

Both calculations are correct. But if you want to get the same date, but one year before, you should simply use '-1 year'. The string '-366 days' is only correct in leap years.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what I was trying to do. I wanted to achieve the date 1 year and 1 day ago, so on a non leap year -366 days would do, however on a leap year this doesn't work as it just gives the same as -1 year.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then use ```strtotime('-1 year -1 day'))``` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = strtotime('2010-01-01 -1 year');
echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

The output stream looks like,

```
2009-01-01
```

[Go this Link for more reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990321/date-minus-1-year)