# Reduce 100 years from a given date in php

Tags: php

```
$date_raw = '05/05/1995';
$newDate = (date('j F Y', strtotime('-192years -14months -2days', strtotime($date_raw))));
print "New Date: $newDate <br>";
```

I'm trying to subtract 100+ years from a given date. but the value i get is real till 92 years only. after that i don't get correct subtraction. whats the reason?

Comment: The simple reason is: `UNIX timestamp`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990321/date-minus-1-year

Comment: If you need to work with dates that fall outside the range of a 32-bit signed unix timestamp (1901-12-13 to 2038-01-19), then start using [DateTime objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: `$date_raw = '05/05/1995';

$newDate = (new DateTime($date_raw))
    ->sub(new DateInterval('P192Y14M2D'))
    ->format('j F Y');
print "New Date: $newDate <br>";`

Comment: any example please?? I'm new to PHP and i did my best to solve this problem. i will be grateful to you if u produce an example for me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to work with dates that fall outside the range of a 32-bit signed unix timestamp (1901-12-13 to 2038-01-19), then start using [DateTime objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$date_raw = '05/05/1995';
$newDate = (new DateTime($date_raw))
    ->sub(new DateInterval('P192Y14M2D'))
    ->format('j F Y');

echo $newDate, PHP_EOL;
```

gives

```
3 March 1802
```

Comment: thanks. accepted this as answer. by the way my question does not deserve to be voted down. i made a deep research about my problem on the internet  before i came here. but whoever did this must be biased to newcomers.

Answer (score 0):

or you can do this in the following way

```
// set your date here

$mydate = "2018-06-27";

/* strtotime accepts two parameters.
The first parameter tells what it should compute.
The second parameter defines what source date it should use. */

$lastHundredyear = strtotime("-100 year", strtotime($mydate));

// format and display the computed date

echo date("Y-m-d", $lastHundredyear);
```

this will give you following output

```
1918-06-27
```

Comment: This can produce illegal dates, like `1918-06-31` which PHP will coerce into it's best guess.