# How to get this day last year in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

So I'm currently using Carbon for getting dates, times and comparisons. I can do subYear() easily enough to get this **date** last year. Now I need something to get the exact same **day** at the same time last year, e.g Wednesday of the second week of April.

I'd expect to have to do something that works out the current day of the week, e.g 3, and the current week of the year, then get the same value last year.

Just thought I'd check if there's anything available that already does this in Carbon or other PHP tools? Thanks

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990321/date-minus-1-year. May be, it is you want

Comment: Thanks splash but that would be the 'date' last year which I can already get using subYear()

Comment: You was looking there to more simpler way :) I've written it in my answer

Comment: There is a problem with the codes. Read my update to answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [`DateTime::setISODate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php) is exactly what you need:

```
$today = new \DateTime();

$year  = (int) $today->format('Y');
$week  = (int) $today->format('W'); // Week of the year
$day   = (int) $today->format('w'); // Day of the week (0 = sunday)

$sameDayLastYear = new \DateTime();
$sameDayLastYear->setISODate($year - 1, $week, $day);

echo "Today: ".$today->format('Y-m-d (l, W)').PHP_EOL;
echo "Same week and day last year: ".$sameDayLastYear->format('Y-m-d (l, W)').PHP_EOL;
```

Output (for today, 2015-05-05):

```
Today: 2015-05-05 (Tuesday, 19)
Same week and day last year: 2014-05-06 (Tuesday, 19)
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else using Carbon you can do a similar solution to splash's and just have:

```
Carbon::now()->subWeeks(52)
```

gives `2014-05-07 14:11:48`

Comment: bare in mind that some years have 53 weeks

Answer (score 2):

Make it easier :)

```
echo date('Y-m-d (l, W)', strtotime("-52 week"));
```

Edit: I forgot to write output: :)

```
2014-05-07 (Wednesday, 19)
```

**UPDATE2:**

There is a problem with jeromegamez' code. A year can contain 52 or 53 weeks. Taking 3 January of 2016:

```
$today = new \DateTime();
$today->setDate ( 2016 , 1 , 3 );

$year  = (int) $today->format('Y');
$week  = (int) $today->format('W'); // Week of the year
$day   = (int) $today->format('w'); // Day of the week (0 = sunday)

$sameDayLastYear = new \DateTime();
$sameDayLastYear->setISODate($year - 1, $week, $day);

echo "Today: ".$today->format('Y-m-d (l, W)').PHP_EOL;
echo "Same week and day last year: ".$sameDayLastYear->format('Y-m-d (l, W)').PHP_EOL;
```

result is:

```
Today: 2016-01-03 (Sunday, 53) 
Same week and day last year: 2015-12-27 (Sunday, 52)
```

only five days instead of years :)

Comment: Yes I've been looking into this and trying to decide whether we want to let the date value to move on longer years so will see

Comment: It not so far as you think. Set date `$today->setDate ( 2016 , 1 , 3 );` You receive `Today: 2016-01-03 (Sunday, 53) Same week and day last year: 2015-12-27 (Sunday, 52)`. only five days instead of years :)

Comment: Look 52 weeks back seems better :)

Answer (score 2):

Something even easier <3

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last year'))
```