# PHP compare current year and last year figure

Tags: php

I have this code, how do i minus 1 year to show the exact last year figure.

For eg: 2016-1-1 compare to 2015-1-1 figure.

```
 $weekno = date('W', strtotime($mthyr.'-'.$j));
    $lastyear = date('Y', strtotime($mthyr.'-'.$j)) - 1;
    $dayinno = date('N', strtotime($mthyr.'-'.$j));
    $gendate = new DateTime();
    $gendate->setISODate($lastyear,$weekno,$dayinno); //year , week num , day
    $lydate = $gendate->format('Ymd');
```

Comment: Try see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990321/date-minus-1-year), I think it's the same with your problem

Comment: why not just use `->modify()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's always the date format you want, how about this?

```
$exploded = explode('-', '2016-1-1');
$exploded[0] -= 1;
print_r(implode('-', $exploded));

// Output:
// 2015-1-1
```

Comment: Hi, do u know  $weekno = date('W', strtotime($mthyr.'-'.$j));
what do this mean?