# How to set current year and previous year in variables using php?

Tags: php, date

- there is one scenario. assume that:
- **financial year =  01/04/2017 to 31/03/2018**
- I have one `input field` with `datepicker` and `date` column in database.
  If any user will select    `today's date e.g 08/06/2017`
- then there should display data for this    `current year i.e from
  01/04/2017 to 08/06/2017` with the help of date    table
- and at the same it should display `previous year's data i.e from
  01/04/2016 to 31/03/2017`
- For the time I am using `$currentdate = date('d/m/Y')` to display
  whole data from db till current date.

`$A1 = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT sum(netvalue) FROM`fintran`WHERE
 groupNo = 21 AND docDate <= "'.$currentdate.'" ');`

We can create some formula but i am so poor to build logic so please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date minus 1 year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990321/date-minus-1-year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Carbon.

Documentation :- http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

```
$date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
$date->subYear(); 
echo $date->format('d/m/Y'); // Previous year
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method for generating date one year back:

```
function get_year_back_date($date, $format='d/m/Y') {
    return date($format, strtotime($date . ' -1 year'));
}

$previous_year = get_year_back_date('01/04/2017');
```

Here you can see this code in action: http://ideone.com/eXRoYB.

Comment: May I suggest: `date('d/m/Y', strtotime('01/04/'. Date("Y") .' -1 year'))` to make it more future safe?

Comment: Or whatever date year the user selects

Comment: @Andreas I've updated my answer to the fairly general function.